# Тип возвращаемого типа, адресное значение, а ожидалось число

Tags: c++

Вычислить сумму элементов вещественной матрицы, находящихся между минимальным и максимальным элементами. Создать функции для:

- определения номера минимального элемента
- определения номера максимального элемента
- определения суммы.
- Функции описать после главной функции

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void minimum(int** mas, int n, int m) {
    int min = mas[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            if (min > mas[i][j]) {
                min = mas[i][j];
            }

    }

    cout << "Минимальный элемент в массиве\t" << min << endl;
}
void maximum(int** mas, int n, int m) {
    int max = mas[0][0];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            if (max < mas[i][j]) {
                max = mas[i][j];
            }

    }
    cout << "Максимальный элемент  в массиве\t" << max << endl;
}
int sum(int min, int max) {
    int summa = 0;
    summa = min + max;
    return summa;
}




int main() {
    int n, m;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    cout << "Вводите матрицу" << endl;
    cin >> n >> m;
    cout << "Вводите значения" << endl;
    int** mas = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        mas[i] = new int [m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cin >> mas[i][j];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "(";
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << mas[i][j];
        cout << ")" << endl;
    }
    minimum( mas,  n,  m);
    maximum(mas, n, m);
    cout << sum;
}
```

Ожидал вывод числа в функции суммирование чисел, а выводит адресное значение. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Вы не вызвали функцию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Функции `minimum` и `maximum` никак не возвращают максимальный и минимальный элемент соответственно. Можно сделать так:

   1. Вернуть `min` и `max` через оператор `return`.

      Например для функции `minimum` так (для `maximum` аналогично):

      ```
      int minimum(int** mas, int n, int m){
          ... //Расчет min
          ... //Вывод min в консоль
          return min;
      }
      int main(){
          ...
          int min = minimum(mas, n, m);
          int max = maximum(mas, n, m);
      }
      ```
   2. Возвращать `min` и `max` через ссылку

      Например для функции `minimum` так (для `maximum` аналогично):

      ```
      void minimum(int** mas, int n, int m, int& min){
          min = mas[0][0];
          ... //Дальнейший расчет min
          ... //Вывод min в консоль
      }
      int main(){
          ...
          int min, max;
          minimum(mas, n, m, min);
          maximum(mas, n, m, max);
      }
      ```
   3. Используя глобальные переменные.

      Для функции `minimum` например так (для `maximum` аналогично):

      ```
      int min;
      void minimum(int** mas, int n, int m){
          min = mas[0][0];
          ... //Расчет min 
          ... //Вывод min
      }
      ```

      Вызов функций из `main` осуществляется так же, как у вас в вопросе.
   4. Так же можно через указатели, но вам лучше выбрать или `1`, `2` или `3` пункт.
2. Далее вы пишите так:

   ```
   cout << sum;
   ```

   Но не передаёте никаких аргументов и поэтому выводится адрес функции.

   Нужно писать так:

   ```
   cout << sum(min, max);
   ```

   `min` и `max` это переменные, которые мы определили одним из `3` методов из `1` пункта
3. Вы пишите, что вам нужно посчитать сумму элементов между максимальным и минимальным элементом матрицы, но функция `sum` просто считает сумму минимального и максимального значения.

   Чтобы найти сумму между максимальным и минимальным элементов, можно например, функции `minimum` и `maximum` изменить так:

   ```
   int minimum(int** mas, int n, int m, int& minRow, int& minCol) {
   //По ссылке передаем minRow и minCol
   int min = mas[0][0];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
           if (min > mas[i][j]) {
               min = mas[i][j];
               //Сохраняем координаты минимального элемента в матрице
               minRow = i;
               minCol = j;
           }
   }
   cout << "Минимальный элемент в массиве\t" << min << endl;
   return min;
   }
   ```

   После завершения функции, через `return` мы получим минимальный элемент, а через ссылки получим его координаты в матрице. Аналогично нужно сделать и в функции `maximum`.

   Потом после того как получили координаты минимального и максимального элемента, нам нужно поменять их местами, т.к. будем проходится циклами по матрице и чтобы не учитывать, `i++` или `i--` сделаем так, чтобы например цикл `i` начинался с минимальной, а заканчивался максимальной координатой.

   Например так (но лучше обмен в функцию вынести):

   ```
   int row1, row2, col1, col2;
   int min = minimum(mas, n, m, row1, col1);
   int max = maximum(mas, n, m, row2, col2);
   int temp;
   if (row1 > row2) {
       temp = row1;
       row1 = row2;
       row2 = temp;
   }
   if (col1 > col2) {
       temp = col1;
       col1 = col2;
       col2 = temp;
   }
   ```

   Теперь `row1` - минимальная строка, `col1` - минимальный столбец

   Дело за малым, просто подсчитать сумму между найденными координатами не учитывая минимальный и максимальный элемент:

   Например так:

   ```
   int summa = 0;
   //Проходимся по матрице
   for (int i = row1; i <= row2; i++) {
       for (int j = col1; j <= col2; j++) {
           //Пропускаем минимальный и максимальный элемент
           if (i == row1 && j == col1) continue;
           if (i == row2 && j == col2) continue;
           //остальное суммируем
           summa += mas[i][j];
       }
   }
   //и возвращаем
   return summa;
   ```

Надеюсь понятно все объяснил. Удачи! :)

Answer (score 2):

Не забывайте скобки при вызове функции (в данном случае ещё и аргументы)

```
cout << sum(minvalue, maxvalue);
```

А чтобы поиметь `minvalue и  maxvalue`, соответствующие функции нужно сделать полноценными - с возвращаемым значением и return

И, наконец, функция суммы считает совсем не то, о чём говорится в задании `сумму элементов вещественной матрицы, находящихся между минимальным и максимальным элементами`

И ещё раз "наконец": функции `minimum` и `maximum` не определяют "номер" соответствующего элемента.